# How to map input value from form to URL of findById()

Tags: java, html, spring, jstl

[/welcome/employees](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m29wR.png)

```
I have a input area where user enters `"empNo"` and clicks on "Find Employee", mapping to be done to /welcome/employees/find/{id}.

[`it should insted be move to url appended with empNo`][2]
```

Here I have everything fine while I directly enter the url, it gives up the result.

but the Find Employee button isn't mapped to entered /welcome/employees/find/{id} instead to /welcome/employees/find/.

and how to map the entered emp No to Find Employee button.Please shed some light.

Controller get employee method working fine only when I manually enter the URL.

```
 list.jsp form page


    <input type="text" path="empNo" value="${employee.empNo}" placeholder="Employee No."/>${employee.empNo}
    &nbsp;
    <a href="/welcome/employees/find/${employee.empNo}" class="btn btn-primary">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span> Find Employee
        </a>




 find.jsp 


    <h2>Employee information</h2>
    <form action="/welcome/employees/find/${employee.empNo}">
    <table class="table table-bordered">
      <tr>
            <th>Employee No.</th>
            <th>First Name</th>
            <th>Last Name</th>
            <th>Gender</th>
            <th>Birth Date</th>


<th>Hire Date</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
        <td>"${employee.empNo}"</td>
        <td>"${employee.firstName}"</td>
        <td>"${employee.lastName}"</td>
        <td>"${employee.gender}"</td>
        <td>"${employee.birthDate}"</td>
        <td>"${employee.hireDate}"</td>
 </tr>
  </table>
</form>
```

Back

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/employees/find/{empNo}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String getEmployee(@PathVariable("empNo") long empNo, Model model){
    Employee employee1=this.employeeService.findEmployeeById(empNo); 
    model.addAttribute(employee1);
    return "employees/find";
}
```

and when I click on find employee it directs to

http://localhost:8080/welcome/employees/find/

Comment: it is the mapping that is not happening, that Find Employee button isn't taking me to the url with {empNo} if i manually enter the URL appended with{empNo} it seems to work fine.

Comment: I think `${employee.empNo}` has no value for `find.jsp` page. Check `${employee.empNo}` gives you anything.

Comment: find.jsp seems to be fine, because manually keying in url with empNo it's working fine but url with empNo isn't mapped to form in list.jsp. I am not sure on how to have user entered empNo mapped to url from form to button and then to url

Comment: i don't see `submit button` in find.jsp. if you're not submitting any data, why don't you just use `<a> tag`?

Comment: i tried changing form to <a> tag it didnt direct to ..../find/{empNo} instead to.../find, once it gets there it is success

Comment: probably it is because I used <a> tag in list.jsp to submit a input form instead of submit??

Comment: `find.jsp` 1) Print `${employee.empNo}` and see if it has some value 2) replace `<form action="/welcome/employees/find/${employee.empNo}">` with `<a href='/welcome/employees/find/${employee.empNo}'` 3) your jsp files are located under the folder called `employees`?

Comment: yes, under employees, now in lits.jsp where I submit input details, I changed those from <a> to form, now the url is like http://localhost:8080/welcome/employees/find/?

Comment: do you think list.jsp is fine, I modified it to this now                                         <c:url var="url"  value="/welcome/employees/find/${employee.empNo}" />
        <form:form action="/welcome/employees/find/${employee.empNo}" method="get" class="form-horizontal"
                   id="search-owner-form">
                        <input class="form-control" placeholder="Employee No."/>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Find Employee</button>
       </form:form>

Comment: Ok so the issue you have is: When you click [Find Employee] link, it goes to `/welcome/employees/find/` instead of `/welcome/employees/find/1`? On listing.jsp, is there any value in ${employee.empNo}? In other word, when you load listing.jsp, your input textbox is empty?

Comment: I keyed in empNo as 1234 which exists in database, since now I changed list.jsp with form elements it directs to /welcome/employees/find/?(please note now url appended with question mark instead of entered empNo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the simple approach without any javascript.

listing.jsp

```
<form action="/welcome/employees/find" method="get"> 
    <input name="empNo" placeholder="Employee No."/> 
    <button type="submit">Find Employee</button> 
</form>
```

Explaination: when you do `${employee.empNo}`, you're getting the value out of the `empNo` variable inside `employee` object. But you don't want to use this value to find. You want to use the value in the textbox to find.

controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/employees/find", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String getEmployee(@RequestParam("empNo") long empNo, Model model){
    Employee employee1=this.employeeService.findEmployeeById(empNo); 
    model.addAttribute(employee1);
    return "employees/find";
}
```

You don't need `<form>` in find.jsp unless you want to do something.

Comment: hi, this seems to work, but now it directs to http://localhost:8080/welcome/employees/find?empNo=1234 , where in the form which shows up details is at http://localhost:8080/welcome/employees/find/1234

Comment: did you make some change controller as I suggested? If you must have url in this form -  localhost:8080/welcome/employees/find/1234, you ll need some javascript.

Comment: oh yeah, I did all these changes that you mentioned here. Replaced from tag in find.jsp with <a> and the above controller code and in list.jsp, now the url directs to localhost:8080/welcome/employees/find?empNo=1234

Comment: Yes I changed everything to as above..now results are like.....1)when i key in emp.no and click find employee it goes to  localhost:8080/welcome/employees/find?empNo=1234 2> modified  to <a> in find.jsp to this <a href="/welcome/employees/find/${employee.empNo}"></a>, now I can't see employee details even if I manually enter url appended with empNo.

Comment: it isn't reaching to find.jsp

Comment: White Label erro, No message available

Comment: Did  it reach `getEmployee` method?

Comment: url is like at  localhost:8080/welcome/employees/find?empNo=1234 didn't get the data there, a white label error "No message available"

Comment: Hey, thanks a lot, it is in working for me, now when i removed /welcome at get employee method